# Tips on Using Easy Clean

Tags: sanitation, cleaning

I got a beer kit and it came with Easy Clean from LD Carlson.  At first I was under the impression that I could use it to clean *and* sanitize.  But now I'm not so sure.  It looks like it was good for both until recently. I think I may be overly-paranoid when it comes to contamination, but want to be certain.  From what I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a clear consensus out there on Easy Clean.

Is it safe to use Easy Clean to sanitize my equipment?  I also end up with a residue after using it, is it ok to rinse tools with tap water before coming in contact with the brew? If Easy Clean isn't good for sanitization, can I use a bleach solution?

Comment: Hi any more info on what this really is " It is a no-rinse oxygen based compound for cleaning beer" not a lot of detail about what it really is

Comment: IIRC, Easy Clean is a sanitizer (but you have to rinse).  Best advice on how to use it -- don't.  Get some Oxyclean (generic) to clean with and a bottle of StarSan to sanitize your equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the product catalog for ld carlson chemicals : http://www.ldcarlson.com/public%20catalog/Chapter%2007.htm

Scroll down to 6019A, which is I believe what you have. No-rinse means it's a sanitizer, if it was just a cleaner they wouldn't call it no-rinse. I've used it many times, and it works great.

Just dilute as it suggests and soak all of your equipment on it. Give the equipment a shake and leave the no-rinse sanitizer on there, it won't impart any flavor to the beer if it's present in small quantities.

Comment: Sure enough, that's what I have.  Thanks for translating no-rinse for me.  I didn't want to assume that's what it meant, but glad to know I can use it in this way.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of government regulations governing what can be labeled as a "Sanitizer". The product may work fine as a sanitizer, but if the company has not gone through the proper government channels and had their product tested as such (and I assume, pay a massive licensing fee to the government), then they can not put that on the label. If it's a product that needs to be rinsed, you will need to rinse it with boiled (or otherwise sanitized) water. Tap water contains micro-organisms (and especially warm tap water), so if you rinse with tap water afterwords, you've forgone the sanitization step. I use Iodaphor (iodine sanitizer) which is a no-rinse sanitizer. A product like starsan would also work well. I clean using oxy-clean soap, then rinse with hot tap water and sanitize with a no rinse product. A bleach solution also works to sanitize, however you must rinse after using bleach, again with sanitized water, or you've forgone that step. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm in SE Asia and can't get some of the products I've read about, good to know I can use bleach in a pinch!

Answer (score 0):

I use the ***LD Carlson Easy Clean***. It is a no-rinse oxygen based compound for cleaning beer and wine-making equipment. Great for removing labels too.
You could also use ***Star San Sanitizer*** it is a foaming acid anionic sanitizer that penetrates hard-to-see places. Both are no rinse and they do not stain and will not impart odors or off flavors. Both are great choices!